# Getting error "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available." while using kafka KStream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am getting the following warning logs while using KStream in my application.

```
2020-03-03 13:15:54,941 [kafka-admin-client-thread | foo-e01eab84-71a8-4bad-906e-ce674ba3f4d7-admin] [WARN ] [CustomerId:] [PrId:] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient] - [AdminClient clientId=foo-e01eab84-71a8-4bad-906e-ce674ba3f4d7-admin] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

2020-03-03 13:15:54,985 [foo-e01eab84-71a8-4bad-906e-ce674ba3f4d7-StreamThread-2] [WARN ] [CustomerId:] [PrId:] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient] - [Consumer clientId=foo-e01eab84-71a8-4bad-906e-ce674ba3f4d7-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=foo] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I am using the below dependencies in pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the spring boot version is:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I am using the following code as my KStream bean:

```
@Bean
public KStream<String, fooEnquiryResponseDto> fooKStream() {
    log.info("Going to create ksream for x face");
    StreamsBuilder builder = fooStreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, fooEnquiryResponseDto> kStreamXFace = builder.stream(fooTopic,
            Consumed.with(stringSerdes, jsonSerdes));
    kStreamXFace.foreach((k, v) -> log.info("message received on foo collection stream with key : {}, value : {}", k, v));

    Arrays.asList(fooStatus.values()).forEach(status -> {
        kStreamXFace.filter((k, v) -> {
            return filterTransaction(v, fooStatus.SUCCESS);
        }).to(fooTopic 
                + "_" + status.toString()
                , Produced.with(stringSerdes, jsonSerdes));
    });

    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), fooStreamProps());
    kafkaStreams.start();
    return kStreamXFace;
}
```

Comment: It means kafka isn't  running where you've connected to

Comment: Kafka is working fine. My producers, consumers and streams are working as expected.

Comment: Is your Kafka and Zookeeper server running? Also, check the IP address and port in your KStreams app's BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG if it's correct or not.

Comment: Hey @CyberKnight, my Kafka and zookeeper servers are running fine and I am able to produce and consume messages. I am more concerned about the logs. As everything is functionally working for me, but still I am getting these warning logs.

Comment: According to the logs, your consumers are not working... Do you get similar logs when not using spring?